# Read a file and convert into an n-ary tree based nested list in Common Lisp?

Tags: parsing, lisp, common-lisp

For one of my projects, I am trying to use Common Lisp, specifically SBCL (in the process, learning it. This is one of the motivations.)

I need to read a file with questions and answers, basically like a Standardized test with mainly multiple choice question answers.

I have some sample questions marked with some section markers like "|" for start and "//s" for and of a section. The question paper will have a hierarchical structure like this: Section -> multiple sub-sections -> each sub-section with multiple questions -> each question will have multiple answers one of them being correct.

This hierarchical structure needs to be converted into a json file finally and pushed to an android app for downstream consumption.

**STEP-1:** After reading from the source Test paper, this is how my list will look like:

```
(("Test" . "t")
 ("0.1" . "v")
 ("today" . "d")
 ("General Knowledge" . "p")
 ("Science" . "s")
 ("what is the speed of light in miles per second?" . "q")
 ("Choose the best answer from the following" . "i")
 ("MCQ question" . "n")
 ("186000" . "c")
 ("286262" . "w")
 ("200000" . "w"))
```

***[PS.1]*** See legend at the end of the post for the explanation of the cdar values like h, p, t , v etc.,

***[PS.2]*** The source file sample attached at the end of this post

Each car of the consed pair representing the content and the cdr representing the section - which will corresponding to a section, sub-section or a question etc.,

**STEP-2:** Finally I need to convert this into the following format - an alist -

```
((:QANDA . "Test") (:VERSION . "0.1") (:DATE . "today")
 (:SECTION
  ((:TITLE . "General Knowledge")
   (:SUBSECTION
    ((:SSTITLE . "Science")
     (:QUESTION
      ((:QUESTION . "what is the speed of light in miles per second?")
       (:DIRECTIONS . "Choose the best answer from the following")
       (:TYPE . "MCQ question")
       (:CHOICES ((:CHOICE . "186000") (:CORRECT . "Y"))
        ((:CHOICE . "286000") (:CORRECT . "N"))
        ((:CHOICE . "200000") (:CORRECT . "N"))))))))))
```

to be consumed by cl-json.

**STEP-3:** cl-json will produce an appropriate json from this.

The json will look like this:

```
 {
  "qanda": "Test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "date": "today",
  "section": [
    {
      "title": "General Knowledge",
      "subsection": [
        {
          "sstitle": "Science",
          "question": [
            {
              "question": "what is the speed of light in miles per second?",
              "Directions": "Choose the best answer from the following",
              "type": "MCQ question",
              "choices": [
                {
                  "choice": "186000",
                  "Correct": "Y"
                },
                {
                  "choice": "286000",
                  "Correct": "N"
                },
                {
                  "choice": "200000",
                  "Correct": "N"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've been successful in reading the source file, generating the consed pair list. Where I am struggling is to create this nested list as shown above to feed it to cl-json.

I realized after a bit of struggle that this is more or less like an n-ary tree problem.

**Here are my questions:**

a) What is the right way to construct such an n-ary tree representation of the Test paper source file?

b) Or is there a better or easier data structure to represent this?

Here is what I tried, where qtree will be '() initially and kvlist is the consed pair list shown above. This is an incomplete code, as I tried push., consing and nconc (with unreliable results).

> Step-1 and Step 3 are fine. Step-2 is where I need help.The problem is to how to add child nodes successively by iterating through the kvlist and find the right parent to add the child when more than one parent is there  (e.g., adding a question to the second sub-section):

```
(defun build-qtree (qtree kvlist)
  (cond
    ((eq '() kvlist) qtree)
    ((equal "h" (cdar kvlist))
     (push (car kvlist) qtree)
     (build-qtree qtree (cdr kvlist)))
    ((equal "p" (cdar kvlist))
     (nconc (last qtree) '((:SECTION))))
    (t
     (qtree))))
```

**[PS.1] Legend:** This will be used in the conditions branches or may be a defstruct or a dictionary type of list etc.,

t - title, v - version, d - date, p - section, s - sub section, q - question, i - instructions, n - type of question, c - correct answer, w - wrong answer

**[PS.2]Source File:**

```
|Test//t
|0.1//v
|today//d
|General Knowledge//p
|Science//s
|what is the speed of light in miles per second?//q
|Choose the best answer from the following//i
|MCQ question//n
|186000//c
|286000//w
|200000//w
```

Comment: All of those three examples seem to represent completely different data. Can you add an actual example of an input file and the data in each different format you want?

Comment: @jkiiski These were all scattered examples I was trying out many things. Sorry about it. Removed them and added one single example throughout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a simple problem with a complex example. It might be just a simple parsing problem: What you need is a grammar and a parser for it.

Example grammar. Terminal items are in upper case. `*` means *one or more*.

```
s = q
q = Q i*
i = I w*
w = W
```

Simple parser:

```
(defun example (sentence)
  (labels ((next-item ()
             (pop sentence))
           (empty? ()
             (null sentence))
           (peek-item ()
             (unless (empty?)
               (first sentence)))
           (expect-item (sym)
             (let ((item (next-item)))
               (if (eq item sym)
                   sym
                 (error "Parser error: next ~a, expected ~a" item sym))))
           (star (sym fn)
             (cons (funcall fn)
                   (loop while (eq (peek-item) sym)
                         collect (funcall fn)))))
    (labels ((s ()
               (q))
             (q ()
               (list (expect-item 'q) (star 'i #'i)))
             (i ()
               (list (expect-item 'i) (star 'w #'w)))
             (w ()
               (expect-item 'w)))
      (s))))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 10 > (example '(q i w w w i w w))
(Q
 ((I (W
      W
      W))
  (I (W
      W))))
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant and cryptic answer. It's not that simple though :-) II needed to define a grammar, read up a bit on compiler theory, peek tokens, etc., Wound up writing a close cousin of recursive descent parsing. Once I got these in place, then changing for other variations of grammar was easy. The beauty of lisp is that I was able to modify the calling levels (i.e., instead of "I"s appearing twice single I with two sub lists) and also could escape creating and inserting parent/ child node functions explicitly, the recursive calling and dynamic list building took care of it.HT to Rainer.